# Django: Can't override admin templates when they are already overridden?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-guardian

To add some content to a Django admin view of a model, I want to override the `change_form.html` template. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) I would need to create a file `change_form.html` in a the folder `/project-path/templates/admin/appname/modelname/`. Of course I need to make sure, that this path is also available in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. Such a file could look like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n  %}

{% block after_field_sets %}
SOME CONTENT
{% endblock %}
```

However, I make use of [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) to have object permissions. This Django app overrides `change_form.html` as well (which works fine -- relevant source seems to be [here](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian/blob/master/guardian/admin.py)), but Django doesn't pick up my template extension file (i.e. "SOME CONTENT" from the sample above isn't displayed). The blocks/parts I want to override are *not* the same ones that django-guardian overrides and eventually I want to have the additions to `change_form.html` of django-guardion *and* of my template.

What am I doing wrong here? And is possible at all to have multiple applications overriding an admin template?

If it is of interest, this is my `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
)
```

Also, django-guardian is the last app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution seems to be to explicitly define the inheritance chain by referring to and overriding django-guardian's template (defined [here](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian/blob/master/guardian/admin.py)) and not Django's general `change_form.html`. So instead of using

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
```

in the beginning of my custom template, I would need to use

```
{% extends "admin/guardian/model/change_form.html" %}
```

Also I would need to extend my `GuardedModelAdmin` sub-class model to explicitly use my own template file as the change form template:

```
class MyModel(GuardedModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'admin/appname/mymodel/change_form.html'
```

This works, but it adds a clear dependency to the template and the model. Of course, the model has this dependency anyway, but I would be interested if there is also a solution that refers only to the default `change_form.html` -- however, I suspect that this is not really possible.

Answer (score 3):

If a path to your template is in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, then you can reverse order of your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`.

If your template in in your app, then you need to add your app **after** django-guardian in `INSTALLED_APPS` array.

Basically, if there are name collisions, then **last** loaded template will be in use.

Comment: the question is no about overriding a template but about overriding them twice when you are using a third party app

Comment: Django will not merge templates automatically and basically you can't override templates twice, but you can add `{% include "admin/guardian/model/change_form.html" %}` in your templates and use only yours.

Comment: Regarding your second point, the documentation and my experience is that from within the INSTALLED_APPS the *first* template Django finds will be used.  So if you are trying to override admin/base_site.html from an app, your app better come first.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader

Comment: @mlncn I wrote it in 2013 and it was valid for Django 1.5. I don't know what's the current status.

Comment: It changed again in Django 1.11. Now you need to use setting 

`FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/renderers/