# Override django change_form.html template when a third app is overriding it

Tags: python, django, templates, django-admin

I am trying to override `change_form.html` only for one model, so I did as explained in [the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and created `/templates/my_app_name/my_model_name/change_form.html`.

The problem is, it is not working and I am not seeing the extra features that I have added to the `change_form` template. I am using `django_guardian`, which also overrides the same template, so my assumption is that this is causing the issue. It is worth mentioning, that before placing the template in the `my_app_name/my_model_name/` folder, the features of both templates were visible in the admin interface.

Is there a way to apply this only for 1 model?

Answer (score 3):

You should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13123854/6916032).

You can specify which template to extend in your template.
So you're extending third app's template which extends djando admin's template.

Example:

**admin.py**

```
class MyModel(ThirdAppModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'my_app_name/templates/change_form.html'
```

**my_app_name/templates/change_form.html**

```
{% extends "thirdapp/templates/change_form.html" %}
{% block thatYouNeed %}
    {{ block.super }}
    Your content here
{% endblock %}
```

Well, at least this is how I managed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The `GuardedModelAdmin` changes `change_form_template` to use the template from django-guardian. Try changing it back in your model admin class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    ...
    change_form_template = 'my_app_name/my_model_name/change_form.html'
```

Comment: Won't I lose the guardian features then?

Comment: You asked how to use your `change_form.html` template. Whether or not your `change_form.html` works with `django-guardian` depends on your template.

Comment: So the solution is to just copy and paste the guardian `change_form.html` in mine and set it using `change_form_template` ?

Comment: That's what I would try doing.